# Objective C - how to Json Parse a dictionary having many dictionaries inside it?

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

Here is the main dictionary - 'query'.

**I want to access 'results'**- It is a NSDictionary having some key - pair values.

But, **all the elements of 'query' dictionary** (i.e count, results, created, lang, diagnostics) are **inside 'query' dictionary's 0th element.**

[image]

This is what I have written to access 'results'.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"restuarant" ofType:@"json"]];

//query is main NSDictionary
self.query = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

//results is an NSDictionary
self.results = [_query valueForKey:@"results"][0];
```

But, when I debug it, everything is getting saved in 'query' variable but **nothing is getting stored in 'results' variable**.

I also tried the following code, but that didn't work out as well -

```
self.results = [_query valueForKey:@"results"];
```

I have looked upon many other stackoverflow pages, but none of them suit my needs. Regards.

Comment: You probably have to show the json input.

Comment: looks like query itself has a key "query" , so try _query[@"query"][@"results"]

Comment: Thanks @TejaNandamuri it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, it should be something like:

```
//results is an NSDictionary
self.results = [[_query valueForKey:@"query"] valueForKey:@"results"];
```

To debug it easier and to understand better the structure, you can also break the access to the results dictionary, into multiple steps, like:

```
NSDictionary *queryDictionary = [_query valueForKey:@"query"];
self.results = [queryDictionary valueForKey:@"results"];
```

then you can check what you have in the first dictionary and then in the second one.

Hope this helps!